# Where does the dark energy of space expansion come from?

Tags: general-relativity, space-expansion, dark-energy

Space has a constant density of dark energy, that means dark energy does not dilute with space expansion. By consequence, any space generated by space expansion does generate new dark energy.

Currently it is supposed that 70% of all energy is dark energy, and that dark energy will continue more and more to be the dominating energy of the universe. Where does this energy come from? Is the law of conservation of energy observed?

Comment: The question I've linked isn't an obvious duplicate, but it does answer your question because it explains that energy is not conserved in spacetimes like an expanding universe where there is no timelike Killing vector. You'll find many more mentions of this on the Physics SE if you search.

Comment: A more primitive question is "why is there a fundamental constant curvature".  Your question assumes that the only way to get this curvature is via the field equations with an energy density.  Perhaps there is another way.